# Tool(s) for cracking insecure RSA keys

Tags: brute-force, rsa

I have a 60-bit RSA public key and a file encrypted with it. Since RSA with keys under 256 bits should be crackable with even limited computational resources, is it possible to obtain the decrypted file?

Comment: https://github.com/Ganapati/RsaCtfTool

Comment: See here [Issues factoring large prime that is 99 digits long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65821907/1820553)